# Pyserial Import Errors Despite Correct Package Installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, pyserial

See the following. "import serial" gives error and I have taken care to import the correct package (pyserial 3.5). I have no idea what the issue is, and other packages have worked fine on this install.

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\python>pip install pyserial
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in c:\users\me\appdata\local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.5)

C:\Users\me\Desktop\python>python
Python 3.10.9 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Mar  1 2023, 18:18:15) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial'
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\anaconda3\python.exe
>>> quit()
```

Comment: Can you post your `PYTHONPATH` environment var, and the result of `sys.path`?

Comment: @BoppreH  >>> print(sys.path)
['', 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']

Answer (score 0):

for pip you did `pip install pyserial` but you only did `import serial` not `import pyserial` so that is probably the problem here. The solution would be `import pyserial`

Comment: pyserial's module is named "serial".